# Spring JPA data base doesn't seen to refresh values that were set to the object in POST method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to set some values to certain object if some contidions are true. It seems like code executes and reaches the "set" lines, but when I send POST request(where this logic is implemented) and then GET method, it seems like it hasn't updated this object.

### This is my Car class:

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cars")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long Id;

    private int yearOfProduction;
    private int price;
    private String color;
    private String brand;
    private String model;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Customer owner;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(int yearOfProduction, int price, String color, String brand, String model) {
        this.yearOfProduction = yearOfProduction;
        this.price = price;
        this.color = color;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

### This is my Customer class:

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;


@Data
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long Id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private int amountOfCash;
    private int actualDiscount;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Car> carList;

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phoneNumber, int amountOfCash, int actualDiscount) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.amountOfCash = amountOfCash;
        this.actualDiscount = actualDiscount;
    }

    public Customer() {
    }


}
```

### This is my POST method when I implement the logic:

```
public ResponseEntity<Customer> buyCar(Long customerID, Long carID) {
        customerRepository
                .findById(customerID)
                .ifPresentOrElse(customer -> {
                    carRepository.findById(carID).ifPresentOrElse(car -> {
                        if (customer.getAmountOfCash() > car.getPrice() * (100 - customer.getActualDiscount()) / 100) {
                            customer.getCarList().add(car);
                            customer.setActualDiscount(customer.getActualDiscount() + 5);
                            customer.setAmountOfCash(customer.getAmountOfCash() -
                                     car.getPrice()* (100 - customer.getActualDiscount()) / 100);
                            car.setOwner(customer);
                        } else {
                            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE,
                                    "Customer doesn't have enough cash");
                        }
                    }, () -> {
                        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Car not found");
                    });
                }, () -> {
                    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Customer not found");
                });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

### This is my GET method:

```
   public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customerRepository.findAll();
    }
```

I also want to add that when I've tried to add the customer once again to the data base like this: customerRepository.save(customer) in POST method, and then I used GET method. The fields have been updated except of the carList, this one was still empty. Also when I print the customer to the console, all of the fields are updated, even carList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set cascade on your `@OneToMany` annotation as `CascadeType.PERSIST)`:

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long Id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private int amountOfCash;
    private int actualDiscount;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Car> carList;

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phoneNumber, int amountOfCash, int actualDiscount) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.amountOfCash = amountOfCash;
        this.actualDiscount = actualDiscount;
    }

    public Customer() {
    }
}
```

This will trigger also the persistence of the `Car` objects in the `carList` property of `Customer`.

There are other cascade types that might be interesting in your use case, so please take a look at the following resources:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types

In addition, add `@Transactional` to your `public ResponseEntity<Customer> buyCar` method as follows:

```java
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<Customer> buyCar(Long customerID, Long carID) {
    customerRepository
        .findById(customerID)
        .ifPresentOrElse(customer -> {
            carRepository.findById(carID).ifPresentOrElse(car -> {
                if (customer.getAmountOfCash() > car.getPrice() * (100 - customer.getActualDiscount()) / 100) {
                    customer.getCarList().add(car);
                    customer.setActualDiscount(customer.getActualDiscount() + 5);
                    customer.setAmountOfCash(customer.getAmountOfCash() -
                             car.getPrice()* (100 - customer.getActualDiscount()) / 100);
                    car.setOwner(customer);
                } else {
                    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE,
                            "Customer doesn't have enough cash");
                }
            }, () -> {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Car not found");
            });
        }, () -> {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Customer not found");
        });
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: After I added this annotation, nothing has changed, none of the fields have been updated.

Comment: Can you please try with `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` instead? These might be merging operations instead. Let me know the outcome.

Comment: Still, it didn't work out. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Ok, that is weird then. Something else must be missing. Are the other fields updated?

Comment: They are acting just as I described just like i described under the code i posted(maybe you missed that), in normal case when I use GET method without saving the customer one more time, none of the fields are updated.

Comment: That is even weirder because Hibernate (I guess you are using it) should understand that the entities were updated and commit the changes to the database.

Comment: Ahh... I don't also understand why when I add the customer one more time, list is not updated but other fields are... this is so weird and I don't  know how to solve that.

Comment: What do you mean by "I add the customer one more time"?

Comment: Just as I described ealier i do: customerRepository.save(customer) in POST method, so basically I ,,add the customer one more time"

Comment: Have you tried calling both `customerRepository.save(customer)` and `carRepository.save(car)`?

Comment: Yes, when I saved both of them it worked fine, but I can't do it like that since I want to set a car to specific customer and then erase car from database, so It's not an option. PS sorry for not replying regularly but I was absent for a couple of days

Comment: Wait, you can't do that. You can't set a car to a specific customer and then delete it from the database. That is not how it works. The entity is exactly the same, so you can't do that. That explains why the `carList` is empty.

Comment: Oh, okay I understand, but it still doesn't explain it, because i wasn't deleting car on the previous version.

Comment: Either you use `carRepository.save(car)` or else you try to find the issue here because as is it should work. I don't think I can help you further, especially because I don't have the full code.

Comment: Here's my repo with full code: https://github.com/jultar2000/Car_Dealer_App , you can check it out if you want. Anyway even if you dont want to let me know, and thank you for your help and attention, I will try to figure something out.

Comment: In addition to the change I suggested in my answer, try adding `@Transactional` to your `public ResponseEntity<Customer> buyCar` method and let me know the outcome.

Comment: It finally worked out, It has given the same result like saving the customer and a car, thank you for your help!

Comment: Awesome! I've updated my answer, please consider accepting it as the correct one so that your question can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!